# OpsGenie Cloudwatch Integration vs Incoming SNS Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, opsgenie

I am using OpsGenie from yesterday. I want to send my cloudwatch alert in OpsGenie Dashboard.

I think there are two integration options possible for this. First one is Cloudwatch Integration and second is Incoming SNS Integration.

I have tested both and both are working fine. What is the difference between those types of integrations: OpsGenie Cloudwatch Integration vs Incoming SNS Integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference between the two is that they work with SNS messages of different format.
CloudWatch integration expects messages in this format: https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/aws-cloudwatch-integration#section-sample-payload-sent-from-cloudwatch
The integration can parse JSON object passed in the `Message` attribute and extract a bunch of parameters that are normally passed with CloudWatch Alarms.

Incoming SNS integration on the other hand doesn't expect SNS messages to be in any particular format but understands some message attributes when they're present: https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/amazon-sns-incoming-integration#section-sample-payload-sent-from-amazon-sns
This integration type is more useful when you want to send alarms yourself from the code whereas CloudWatch Alarms are sent by AWS.